# Why is my list getting null values?

Tags: java, android

I have a project that I need to parse some `JSON` from the `Google Places API` but my `List` is getting null values or no values at all. So in my `MyActivity.java` in my `onPostExecute` method when I try the following it is not parsing the values and returning them. It is creating the objects in the `JSONParser` class but not getting them in my onPostExecute method?

> placeList = JSONParser.parseFeed(result);

Here is my code:

#### MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // create some references for ui elements
    EditText urlText;
    TextView textView;
    ProgressBar pb;
    // create a reference to the list's needed for data
    List<MyTask> tasks;
    List<Places> placeList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        // get my ui elements by id
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        // set the progress bar to invisible
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //initiate my tasks
        tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        // make text view scrollable
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // the method for when the button is clicked
    public void myClick(View view) {
        // create a string to grab the text of the edit text
        String myString = urlText.getText().toString();
        // replace the spaces with + to encode into the url
        String encodedString = myString.replace(" ", "+");
        //check to see if online and if so continue to get the JSON data if not toast a message telling the user no connection
        if (isOnline()) {
            requestData("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" + encodedString + "&key=AIzaSyB9iOw6wF4FwbOdUTZYiU_MxsbfWM5iMOI");
        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    // method to update th ui
    protected void updateDisplay() {
        if (placeList != null) {
            for (Places place : placeList) {
                textView.append(place.getName());
            }
        }


    }

    // method to check internet connectivity
    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    }

    // method to get the data from ASYNC task
    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    // Async task method to do network action in
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                // set the progress bar to visible while Async task is running
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            // add this to the task
            tasks.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            placeList = JSONParser.parseFeed(result);
            Log.v("message:", String.valueOf(placeList));
            updateDisplay();

            tasks.remove(this);
            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                // remove progress bar visibility from ui
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            //updateDisplay(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

#### JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

public static List<Places> parseFeed(String content) {

    JSONObject myObj;
    try {
        myObj = new JSONObject(content);
        JSONArray result = myObj.getJSONArray("results");
        List<Places> placeList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
            Places place = new Places();
            place.setName(obj.getString("name"));
           // place.setFormatted_address(obj.getString("formatted_address"));
           // place.setTypes(obj.getString("types"));
            //place.setPhotos(obj.getString("photos"));

            placeList.add(place);
        }
        return placeList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

  }

}
```

#### Places.java

```
public class Places {

    private String pName;
    private String pTypes;
    private String pFormatted_address;
    private String pPhotos;


    public  Places(){
        pName ="";
        pTypes ="";
        pFormatted_address = "";
        pPhotos="";
    }

    public Places (String _name, String _types, String _formatted_address, String _photos){
        pName = _name;
        pTypes =_types;
        pFormatted_address = _formatted_address;
        pPhotos = _photos;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return pName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        pName = name;
    }
    public String getTypes() {
        return pTypes;
    }
    public void  setTypes(String types) {
        pTypes= types;
    }
    public String getFormatted_address() {
        return pFormatted_address;
    }
    public void setFormatted_address(String formatted_address) {
        pFormatted_address=formatted_address;
    }
    public String getPhotos() {
        return pPhotos;
    }
    public void setPhotos(String photos) {
        pPhotos= photos;
    }


}
```

#### Activity_my.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myUrl"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myBUtton"
        android:text="@string/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClick" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### JSON

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 34.0522342,
                    "lng": -118.2436849
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 34.3373061,
                        "lng": -118.1552891
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 33.7036917,
                        "lng": -118.6681759
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
            "id": "7f7b7d8118ae8db8ed3f541159ac928c484d12ad",
            "name": "Los Angeles",
            "place_id": "ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I",
            "reference": "CoQBfwAAADOao2DI1Kxx7JS6g1utfzjgmiioj3ZoGgn26YmDJSlpkz9sZBuRMdUkytjNTMrK8isWwhnpuJ7EyVBhL0tXiFz-yS4qizi7eeA7olH5WNZude3IYd9iCq_MrigWxqop0_WsSaR9qU57wG8VTQzn7TQHEURmsC5ZARkjGfVk-unJEhARVD57imH0qkFsJCHx7RfbGhST3GV5RcklBl_-9kjAaLZ3KuNY5A",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Could you post the JSON you're attempting to parse? Have you inserted a breakpoint where you attempt to parse the response and verified that the results object exists?

Comment: That is one object from the JSON, my JSON is too big to post. @Chris Yes I did that in the JavaParser class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are parsing one more object than you should, which will throw an exception and return `null`:

```
// replace <= with just <                              
for (int i = 0; i <= result.length(); i++) {
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: I can't vote up because rep is still a little too low but this is the correct answer! Thank you.